# Returning paginated eloquent models with custom JSON schema?

Tags: php, json, laravel, pagination, eloquent

I'm working on an API in Laravel 4, and right now when I return paginated info in JSON format it comes back in this specific format:

```
    {
        "Photos":{
            "total":1,
            "per_page":15,
            "current_page":1,
            "last_page":1,
            "from":1,
            "to":1,
            "data":[
                {
                    "id":3,
                    "moreInfo":"..."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

But I want my API to instead return the information in this format:

```
    {
        "total":1,
        "per_page":15,
        "current_page":1,
        "last_page":1,
        "from":1,
        "to":1,
        "Photos":[
            {
                "id":3,
                "moreInfo":"..."
            }
        ]
    }
```

The relevant code looks like:

```
    if (Input::has('page')) {
        $limit = (Input::get('limit')) ? Input::get('limit') : 15;

        return Response::json([
            'Photos' => $photos->paginate($limit)->toArray()
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: If you don't like Laravels `data` key, then manually rename it to `Photos`. Then just lose the exra `['Photos'=>` wrapping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first I didn't realize how simple this actually is, I tried getting data via the `Pagination->getItems()` and `Pagination->getCollection()`.

I realized all I had to do was get the ['data'] section from the pagination. My code now looks like:

```
    if (Input::has('page')) {
        $limit = (Input::get('limit')) ? Input::get('limit') : 15;

        $pagedPhotos = $photos->paginate($limit);

        return Response::json([
            'total' => $pagedPhotos->getTotal(),
            'per_page' => $pagedPhotos->getPerPage(),
            'current_page' => $pagedPhotos->getCurrentPage(),
            'last_page' => $pagedPhotos->getLastPage(),
            'from' => $pagedPhotos->getFrom(),
            'to' => $pagedPhotos->getTo(),
            'Photos' => $photos->paginate($limit)->toArray()['data']
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So strip out the `photos` component:

```
return Response::json($photos->paginate($limit)->toArray())
```

Comment: That returns the response in my first example, but the items are still in `[data]`

Comment: then you need to take that array that paginate is building and mangle it yourself. If you want a custom format, then you have to write the code to produce that form.

Comment: Yeah, I realized lol. I was over complicating it trying to figure out how to get the data from the Pagination class via some method when I can just access the array it returns :(. Thanks, you can update your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest Laravel 10 the following solution is most appropriate:

`app/Pagination/MyPaginator.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Pagination;

use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class MyPaginator extends LengthAwarePaginator
{
    /**
     * Get the instance as an array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'data'         => $this->items->toArray(),
            'current_page' => $this->currentPage(),
            'from'         => $this->firstItem(),
            'last_page'    => $this->lastPage(),
            'per_page'     => $this->perPage(),
            'to'           => $this->lastItem(),
            'total'        => $this->total(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`:

```php
use App\Pagination\MyPaginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as LengthAwarePaginatorContract;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->alias(MyPaginator::class, LengthAwarePaginator::class);
    $this->app->alias(MyPaginator::class, LengthAwarePaginatorContract::class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to customize the json pagination (I'm using Inertia/vue3) following your instructions.

This is by far the best answer to this topic

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9 this works different, to customize the response for Paginator the code should looks like this:

```
$myCommunityActivities = CommunityActivity::where('member_id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(10);

$results = [
   'total' => $myCommunityActivities->total(),
   'per_page' => $myCommunityActivities->perPage(),
   'current_page' => $myCommunityActivities->currentPage(),
   'last_page' => $myCommunityActivities->lastPage(),
   'activities' => $myCommunityActivities->items()
];

return response()->json($results, 200);
```